# Porterduff, set alpha / strength level

Tags: java, android, image-processing, paint, porter-duff

Im currently trying out the porterduff-modes in my android app. Im doing this with these lines:

```
        Canvas c = new Canvas(output);                                                                              
        maskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        maskPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
        maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));

        c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, p);   
        c.drawBitmap(overlay, 0,0,maskPaint);
```

I have my bitmap as I blend the overlay into, by using the PorterDuff modes. Now, im wondering if there is any function to set the strength level of the blending.

Without the porterduffmode I can get a blending effect by only changing the Alpha values of the overlay.

How can I get a hard/soft blend with porterduff?

Thanks!